# Project ERROR: Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the license agreement by running /usr/bin/xcodebuild

Tags: xcode, macos, qt-creator

I am running into issues installing the ckb app found at (https://github.com/ccMSC/ckb/blob/master/README.md) so that I can implement dynamic lighting for my Corsair keyboard on Mac OS X 10.11.6

- I followed the README.md but clicking on ckb.pkg appears to have installed the incorrect version of the ckb.app. The UI says "No devices connected", the keyboard lights are not programmable, and it doesn't show anything else other than settings (there is no keyboard ui as displayed in the image on git).
- Running "sudo xcodebuild -license" initially appears to succeed but then fails to cure the recurring xcode license prompt after re-running the quickbuild file from ckb-master (also tried to change to read/write for Library/Preferences but I receive prompt indicating I lack permission to do so).
- I followed BUILD.md and used QT Creator resulting in the following error: "Project ERROR: Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the license agreement by running /usr/bin/xcodebuild.
  Error while parsing file /Users/ivanfan/Desktop/ckb-master 10.54.34 PM/ckb.pro. Giving up."

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated - thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are you able to open Xcode successfully from Finder or Spotlight?

Comment: Do you have both Xcode7 and Xcode 8 (i.e. multiple copies of Xcode) installed on your machine?

Comment: I was able to open Xcode successfully @MrEricSir. Hilarious username btw lol -

Comment: I have Xcode 8 installed on my machine (is there an easy way to check if I have multiple copies of an application installed? all I did was look in my applications folder) @Michael .